# whatsapp group ...what does the message so and so was removed mean?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

In a whatsapp group, what does the message `Username` was removed mean?

- Did the admin remove that person ?
- Did that person delete the account?
- "`Username` left" is different from "`Username` was removed", right?

Answer (score 4):

When you see a message `<User> was removed` then it means two things:

1. The group admin removed the user from group.
2. The person deleted/deactivated his account. I can vouch for this one because my friend lost his mobile and on deactivation the message appeared in my group that he was removed without me taking action.

Yes, `<User> was removed` and `<User> has left` mean two different things, `<User> has left` comes up when user voluntarily leaves a group but keeps his WhatsApp active.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the difference one one getting removed by others(group admin) and one leaving group by self.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if admin of group removed a person from the group then , whatsapp will "Username was removed",

If the person in a group left the group then it will show "Username left"..

It is not means user deleted the account

Comment: It looks like Naveen has anecdotal evidence to back up his claim that this can also mean that the user deactivated his WhatsApp account. Could you be mistaken or should he reconsider his answer?

Comment: i forgot to mention the scenario what naveen mentioned .

Answer (score 0):

If the admin itself goes off from the group before removing all the other members then it shows this message about the admin to the other remaining members left behind in the group.

Answer (score 0):

What I have experienced in my WhatsApp groups is that

1. "User was removed" means he/she deleted or deactivated his/her account.
2. "adminuser removed user" means admin removed that particular user.
3. "User left" means user left the group.

This I have experienced in last 2/3 versions of Whatsapp. But I don't know exactly if it is same or not for older versions of Whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is different from what you said above.

If admin removes someone then it write "admin name" removed "username" 
If user leaves groups it writes "user name left"
"user name was removed" in my group happens when someone stays too long without activity in WhatsApp. Their personal account remains available but they have been inactive for a long time.

I think there is an inbuilt program that removes these people from groups, which to me is a good thing.

Answer (score -1):

I'm the admin of my group and i did not remove my friend yet the message appeared "user was removed"

I think when someone deactivates their account then this message comes
but maybe there is one more possibility, if that user blocks the admin then he/she might be getting removed from all the groups where the same person is the admin whom he/she has blocked.

And yes if the admin removes that person then also 'user was removed' will show